# github actions catkin build example?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have a github actions (https://github.com/features/actions) catkin build example?

I imagine I can cut and paste a lot from a .travis.yml (https://github.com/lucasw/image_to_v4l2loopback/blob/master/.travis.yml for example), but haven't gotten too far into it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336103/github-actions-catkin-build-example?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2019-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got something working here: https://github.com/lucasw/frei0r_image/blob/master/.github/workflows/ubuntu_20_04.yml
(see also https://github.com/lucasw/frei0r_image/actions for how the results are reported)

```
name: Noetic Ubuntu 20.04

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    env:
      ROS_CI_DESKTOP: "`lsb_release -cs`"  # e.g. [trusty|xenial|...]
      ROS_DISTRO: noetic
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Non-ROS Dependencies
        run: |
            ls -l $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
            sudo apt-get install -y frei0r-plugins-dev
      - name: Install ROS
        run: |
            sudo sh -c "echo \"deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $ROS_CI_DESKTOP main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list"
            sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
            sudo apt-get update -qq
            sudo apt-get install dpkg
            sudo apt-get install -y python3-catkin-pkg
            sudo apt-get install -y python3-catkin-tools
            sudo apt-get install -y python3-osrf-pycommon
            sudo apt-get install -y python3-rosdep
            sudo apt-get install -y python3-wstool
            sudo apt-get install -y ros-cmake-modules
            sudo apt-get install -y ros-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin
            source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
      - name: Install ROS packages with rosdep
        run: |
          source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
          sudo rosdep init
          rosdep update
          mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
          ln -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE ~/catkin_ws/src/frei0r_image
          cd ~/catkin_ws
          rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -s  # do a dry-run first
          rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
      - name: catkin build
        run: |
          source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
          cd ~/catkin_ws
          catkin build --no-status
          source devel/setup.bash
      - name: lint
        run: |
          cd ~/catkin_ws
          catkin build frei0r_image --no-deps --catkin-make-args roslint
```

It would be fantastic if there was a `ubuntu-20.04` target image that already has noetic on it to speed up the build.  (In other contexts I've seen downloading a large custom pre-installed image is slower than starting with a clean base image and installing everything from highly available apt repos, but I'm sure that can vary wildly).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2019-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-03-30**:
For **build**, why is the second `catkin build` required? Is the symbolic link for some added functionality?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-03-30**:
I'm not sure why I did that, I had just got it working when I posted it, I'll clean it up later.  Here's a more up-to-date example for 20.04, no symlink because the checkout puts the source into the right catkin_ws path

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/7a284cad5057f4014f999a20aa3b3e12ad471de1/.github/workflows/ubuntu_20_04.yml

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-04-02**:
Thanks for the new example. After mucking around, I can confirm "*source is checked out to `~/work`, which may not be true forever*" still holds true. As for the two `catkin build` you do, I'm theorizing the second one is to create a symbolic link to `~/work` and then catkin build again in case the first one was done on an empty `/src`.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-04-02**:
I update the action to get rid of that anyhow, maybe later it could do also do catkin install build and zip up the install contents and push that into the github actions build artfiacts so it can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Industrial CI has support for varoius CI pipelines, among them also [Github actions](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/tree/master#for-github-actions).

---

Originally posted by [Thazz](https://answers.ros.org/users/39841/thazz/) with karma: 66 on 2020-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3